# Scene Builder 2.0: how to set HBox spacing?

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I can easily set up HBox's spacing programmatically (through constructor or setter method), but how can I do it on Scene Builder? I can't seem to find a place where I can enter that information.

Comment: Adding it into fxml file is suitable for you?

Comment: That would work, but it would be nice to know how to do it right there at SB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [SceneBuilder 8.0](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/), but I think the property is located in the same place in the previous versions.

With an `HBox` selected, expand the "Layout" pane on the right (below "Properties" and above "Code"); the `spacing` property is the second one down, after `padding` and in the "Internal" section, in that pane:

[image]